# Laptop is running hot!

Tags: 12.04, laptop, vaio, sony, temperature

I have a sony  VPCEH15EN laptop with ubuntu 12.04 installed.  My laptop runs normally in windows but it is running hot in ubuntu. I have installed jupiter and tlp also.Jupiter shows that temperature is about 68'C
Thank you.
Running `top` gave the following output:

```
top - 20:13:04 up  2:55,  3 users,  load average: 1.85, 1.67, 1.33
Tasks: 162 total,   1 running, 161 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.0%us,  3.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 79.3%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1928868k total,  1596984k used,   331884k free,    45956k buffers
Swap:  2038780k total,    11172k used,  2027608k free,   732020k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
18488 sony      20   0  566m  27m  18m S   25  1.4   6:23.45 gnome-system-mo    
 6568 root      20   0  124m  20m 5580 S   22  1.1  20:07.93 Xorg               
17462 sony      20   0 1378m 337m  48m S    9 17.9   7:35.35 firefox            
 6956 sony      20   0  599m  27m 4372 S    7  1.5   6:58.50 conky              
 7369 sony      20   0  613m  19m  11m S    7  1.0   1:45.87 gnome-terminal     
 6796 sony      20   0 1888m 151m  37m S    7  8.0   6:36.23 gnome-shell        
 6774 sony      20   0  934m  19m  13m S    0  1.1   0:06.15 gnome-settings-    
 6806 sony      20   0  686m  16m  11m S    0  0.9   0:02.69 nm-applet          
 6829 sony      20   0  828m  22m  11m S    0  1.2   0:08.13 python             
 8910 root      20   0 22188 3616  840 S    0  0.2   0:37.71 airodump-ng        
17457 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.29 kworker/u:1        
    1 root      20   0 24592 2288 1288 S    0  0.1   0:00.82 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:03.35 ksoftirqd/0        
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.03 migration/0        
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.07 migration/1        
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.91 ksoftirqd/1
```

`lspci | grep VGA` gave the following output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: From memory a number of Sony laptops require the proprietary video drivers to be installed for proper power management and fan control. Have you checked in System Settings, Additional Drivers yet?

Comment: I did and no additional drivers were suggested.

Comment: Post the output of "lspci | grep VGA" here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abnormal heat occurs due to CPU temperature issues normally. I do no know why it acts weird only in Ubuntu. BTW, try to open up **terminal** by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (if you're in GUI) & type `top` then post the output. Also have a look at this **[post](https://superuser.com/questions/25176/how-can-i-monitor-the-cpu-temperature-under-linux)** too...